# How to print a set of numbers using repeat/0 in prolog?

Tags: prolog

in an exercice I have to write a predicate that prints numbers < N using repeat/0, here is what I have tried :

```
loop(N) :-
    repeat,
        write(N), nl,
        N is N-1,
        write(N),
        N > 0,
    !.
```

but it only prints the given number N Endlessly.

Any Idea how to implement this using `repeat/0` ?? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
loop(N) :-
        between(1, N, X),
        writeln(X),
        false.
```

Comment: Doesn't use repeat. which is required. Notice that yous predicate loop/1 fails while the others succeed.

Comment: Or when you want success of the predicate loop/1, you can also replace ..., false, by ..., false; true.

Comment: repeat/0 is senseless in this case - you can stick it after false/0 if you insist it show up. Notice also that for example `?- loop(-3)` loops with the other versions while it terminates with mine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use assert/retract eg

```
:- dynamic value/1.
loop(N) :-
    retractall(value(_)),
    assert(value(N)),
    repeat,
            retract(value(V)),
            writeln(V),
            V1 is V - 1,
            assert(value(V1)),
            V = 0,
    !.
```

Comment: Thans for your reply. But at this point, I don't think that we are allowed to use these predicates you showed me. (dynamic, rectratcall, assert, retract). All we are allowed to use is, `repeat/0` & `between/3`, the cut `!` and the basic controllers, no more :/

Comment: Adding dynamic over something as simple as a loop seems like a bad practice to me.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got to make it work using the predicate `between/3` this is my final code :

```
loop(N) :-
    repeat,
        between(1, N, X),
        writeln(X),
        X = N,
    !.
```

Edit :
as @CookieMonster said, `repeat/0` is not needed, so here is the last version of the code :

```
loop(N) :-
        between(1, N, X),
        writeln(X),
        false.
```

Comment: The repeat in the above is not needed. You can try it by yourself, and remove the repeat, it will work exactly the same. One you should also tell your teacher that combining repeat and between doesn't make sense.

Comment: repeat is only for infinite looping where you have no generator. But between is already generator. You also don't need the X=N, !, between does it already for you. Replace this by fail.

Comment: @CookieMonster Thank you for your explanations, it really makes sense, and I have learned from you here.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI: This ! at the end is useles. Stick to mat's solution!

Comment: @false thanks. would you have an answer for my question I posted on Anniepoo's Anser ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13325860/614277

Answer (score 2):

Your original one doesn't work for various reasons, but in particular

```
loop(N) :-
    repeat,
        write(N), nl,
        N is N-1,                <--- no!
        write(N),
        N > 0,
    !.
```

"is"  unifies if the left side is the mathematical result of the right. 
the left side will be bound to the right.
you can't change the value of a var once you've set it in Prolog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have noticed that the "is" was not working, but failed to deduct the reason. So, If I cannot do it this way, is there an other way around to use a Variable that decrements each time `repeat` loops ?

Comment: 'Variables' aren't 'Variable' in Prolog So you'd either do it recursively, or use something like between that hands out a succession of numbers

Answer (score 1):

Abderrahmane asked about how to decrement.

Couple ways to do this. Most people would do

```
dec(0).
dec(N) :-
   write(N), nl,
   NewN is N - 1,
   dec(NewN).
```

if you insist on a failure driven loop, how about

```
dec(N) :-
    between(1,N,X),
    Dec is 11 - X,
    write(Dec), nl,
    Dec = 1.
```

or, and this is ugly and bad style (and slow as molasses):

```
dec(N) :-
      assert(current_n(N)),
      repeat,
      current_n(Y),
      write(Y), nl,
      NewY is Y - 1,
      retractall(current_n(_)).
      assert(current_n(NewY)),
      Y > 0.
```

Comment: Beware! Your first definition does not terminate: `dec(1), false`

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce a service predicate

```
isint(I) :- I = 0 ; isint(T), I is T + 1.
```

this is needed to scope in a *new* variable (practically solve the point that Anniepoo highlighted in her first response).

Then I could write

```
loop(N) :-
  repeat,
  isint(I),
  write(I), nl,
  I >= N, !.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way :

```
loop(N) :-
    between(1, N, X),
    writeln(X),
    X >= N, !.
    loop(X).
```